# How do I convert a basic code snippit/pattern to use c+11 variadic templates

Tags: c++, template-specialization, variadic-templates

The following simple code pattern is very common in graphics programming.
It creates an array of layers and loops over them.

```
struct Layer
{
    int n;
    void operator()(float value)
    {
    }
};

struct AnotherLayer
{
    int n;
    int m;
    void operator()(float value)
    {
    }
};

void process_layers(Layer_t* layer, size_t size, float value) 
{
    for (size_t n = 0; n < size; ++n)
        layer[n](value);
}

Layer a = {1};
Layer b = {2};
AnotherLayer c = {2,3};
typedef std::function < void (float) > Layer_t;
Layer_t layers [] = {a,b,c};
process_layers(layers, sizeof(layers)/sizeof(Layer), 100);
```

I would like to convert this to use varadic templates in c++11.  Any ideas how I could do this.  This is what I would like it to look like.  Any ideas?  Is this even possible?

```
template <int n>
struct Layer
{
    void operator()(float value)
    {
    }
};

template <int n, int m>
struct AnotherLayer
{
    void operator()(float value)
    {
    }
};

template <typename Layer1, typename Layer2, ...>
struct Layers  //process_layers
{
    void operator()(float value)
    {
        for (size_t n = 0; n < SIZEOF(Layer1,Layer2,...); ++n)
            Layer[N]()(value);
    }
};
```

Then I could do this.

```
typedef Layers<Layer<1>, Layer<2>, AnotherLayer<3,8> > funky_layer_t;
typedef Layers<Layer<4>, Layer<5>, Layer<5>, AnotherLayer<6,7> > standard_layer_t;
typedef Layers<funky_layer_t, standard_layer_t> awesome_layer_t;

awesome_layer_t()(100);
```

Note: with the second approach, all paramaters to construct layers are known at compile time.

Comment: That isn't a very constructive use of variadic templates. Templates are a compile time construct to handle various types. Just use a `std::vector<Layer>` to have a variable sized array that can shrink, grow, iterate, etc.

Comment: Why template layer class is better for you? What is the effort of templates here? I have really bad experience on C++ codes, where templates where forced to use (_The previous coder had a really good book on templates..._ :) ).

Comment: Then I could, at compile time, construct very complex combinations of layers.  For example:

    typedef Layers<gray_layer_t,gaussian_filter_t,opaque50_t> clean_layer_t;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you give is very simple to re-do with variadic templates.

```
template<typename Func> void process(Func &&f) {} // base case for zero items

// overload for at least one item
template<typename Func, typename FirstItem, typename... Items>
void process(Func &&f, FirstItem &&fi, Items &&...is) {
    std::forward<Func>(f)(std::forward<FirstItem>(fi));          // f(fi);
    process(std::forward<Func>(f), std::forward<Items>(is)...);  // process(f,is...);
}

Layer a = {1};
Layer b = {2};
Layer c = {3};

process([](Layer &l){ l(100); },
        a, b, c);
```

Also notice that this avoids all the unnecessary copies in the original. (Though of course you could also avoid them just by doing `Layer layers[] = {{1},{2},{3}};`)

---

I'm not exactly sure how your later comments and code are related to running an operation over a collection of layers.

What exactly is the computation you want to perform at compile-time?

---

To adjust for the new example the `process()` does not need to change at all, you only need to  create a functor that can handle each type. (polymorphic lambdas would help here, but we'll have to make due with an explicit functor type)

```
Layer a = {1};
Layer b = {2};
AnotherLayer c = {2,3};

struct TheOperation {
    template<typename T>
    void operator() (T &t) {
        t(100);
    }
};

process(TheOperation(),
    a, b, c);
```

---

Here's your `awesome_layer_t` transcribed to correct variadic template syntax, but I still don't see what you want to accomplish, so I can't say if this is a good way to do it or not. This doesn't actually call the `operator()`s at compile-time, it only arranges to have a bunch of objects default constructed at runtime and then `operator()` called, again, at runtime.

```
template <int n>
struct Layer
{
    int operator()(float value)
    {
        std::printf("L %d %e\n",n,value);
        return 0;
    }
};

template <int n, int m>
struct AnotherLayer
{
    int operator()(float value)
    {
        std::printf("AL %d %d %e\n",n,m,value);
        return 0;
    }
};

template <typename... Ls>
struct Layers  //process_layers
{
    int operator()(float value)
    {
        struct Tmp {
            void operator() (...) {}
        };
        Tmp()( Ls()(value)...);
        return 0;
    }
};

typedef Layers<Layer<1>, Layer<2>, AnotherLayer<3,8> > funky_layer_t;
typedef Layers<Layer<4>, Layer<5>, Layer<5>, AnotherLayer<6,7> > standard_layer_t;
typedef Layers<funky_layer_t, standard_layer_t> awesome_layer_t;

int main() {
    awesome_layer_t()(100);
}
```

Comment: I have not tried this, but the motivating reason for looking for new pattern is to construct complext combinations of layers at compile time.  I dont see how your example moves us in that direction.   

Also, your process function is a tad hard to understand, with all those std::forward's.

Comment: >> What exactly is the computation you want to perform at compile-time?

This is purely for synactic sugar.  I want to pass an image buffer through each layer.

Comment: >> Layer layers[] = {{1},{2},{3}}

This wont work, because it assumes each layer will have the same constructor.  Each layer could be very different from each other.  The only similar thing is the operator()(int) prototype.

Comment: In your example the type of `Layer` seems completely irrelevant. It could be some massively complex constructed type or an int, so long as whatever operation you're performing works on it. So what is stopping you from constructing whatever types you want and processing them this way?

Comment: You're using a raw array of `Layer`, so the types have to be the same anyway to avoid slicing, etc.

Comment: Yep, your correct.  I've changed example to use std::function instead.

Comment: So I show your new example transformed to use my `process()`. Also I added comments to the definition of `process()` so you can see that each line is really quite simple.

Comment: Ok, I see where your going with that.  Thanks.  That just might work for layers that are constructed at runtime.  

Also, I've updated my example to have compile time constructed layers (ie, moved constructor to template header).   I wonder if your example will also work for that as well.

Comment: >>but I still don't see what you want to accomplish.  

Replace float value with: Image* img.  You can pass an image buffer through a complex set of layers, say you wanted to convert it to gray, then resize it, than warp it, then whatever.   If your sample, compiles, that will be aweseome.  I'll try it tonight.

Comment: I think if you want to create a pipeline of operations you might instead want to look at `std::bind()`. `auto percent_change = bind(std::multiplies<double>(),bind(std::divides<double>(), bind(std::minus<double>(),_2,_1),_1),100.0); std::cout << percent_change(100,101) << '\n';`

Comment: Or lambdas: `auto percent_change = [](double a, double b) { return (b-a)/a; };`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can do this using normal function templates as follows:

```
/* Base case: If you have no layers to apply, do nothing. */
void executeLayers() {
    // Deliberately empty.
}

/* Recursive step: If you have at least one layer, apply it, then apply the
 * remaining layers.
 */
template <typename Head, typename... Tail> 
void executeLayers(Head head, Tail... tail) {
    head();              // Execute the first layer
    executeLayers(tail); // Execute the remaining layers
}
```

You could then do something like this:

```
executeLayers(layer1, layer2, layer3, layer4, layer5);
```

Hope this helps!